# Math background for approximating a projective transformation by an affine transformation

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, projective-geometry

I am mentioning 2d transformation as described in [lecture](https://ags.cs.uni-kl.de/fileadmin/inf_ags/3dcv-ws17-18/Lec03_Homographies.pdf). A snapshot from the types of transformation 
[image]

what is the analysis (in terms of relative and absolute accuracy) necessary or to find an approximation of a given a projective transformation $P \in R^{3\times 3} $ at a given point $q \in R^{3\times 1} $ (so the transformation is $ f=Pq $) by an affine one $f^*$. This unknown affine transformation is parameterized by $a_{11}, a_{12}, t_x, a_{21}, a_{22}, t_y$ as shown in the picture.

As I understand, the relative error is defined by $ E=(f-f^*)/f $

is it possible to have such analysis for the approximation accuracy and solving the unknowns simultaneously?

Thank you